# favicon not showing when website is viewes

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

M designing a website using DW. I wanted to add a favicon to my website so when I did and view the website, it dsn't show up the icon. I used a 16 x 16 png as the image and the coding is given below. what might I have done wrong. please help me!

thank you.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
```

Comment: What browser does it not display in? Also use `shortcut icon`, not just `icon`.

Comment: it's in every browser. nd I tried with that too. bt nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer does not support a PNG favicon.

What you should do, is setup your `<link` tag like so:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
```

For IE, and legacy browsers, also keep a less-pretty (by the fact it's an ICO, not intentionally!) version of your icon in .ico format in the root of your site named `favicon.ico`. You can use http://icoconverter.com/ to convert your PNG to an ICO. Don't just rename `favicon.png` to `favicon.ico` and expect it to work.

Comment: I've checked it with an ico I created bt it still doesn't work. Is there a way to add a favicon using a wizard or something in DW cs5.

Comment: it showed up in Firefox now bt not in chrome. what can be wrong now?

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri It should work fine, just remember that different browsers show the icons in different places.

Answer (score 1):

wrong file extension.. it's supposed to be `.ico` instead of `.png`

go here for all the info:

http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/

**EDIT:**

Try going on the link and converting your favicon to `ico`

then add this `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">` to your main page.

make sure the favicon exists in that directory.

Comment: Not particularly, it can be of any type and still get pretty widespread support. Without hinting using the `<link` tag, then yes, the default is `favicon.ico` in the site root.

Comment: I tried with .ico too. bt no good. it still dsn't show up. I dnt knw what the reason is!

Comment: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.png" />` works just fine for github. It does not need to be a `.ico`

Comment: @andyb Actually for IE, GitHub still provides the `favicon.ico`. The PNG is only used in supported browsers like I said in my answer - https://github.com/favicon.ico

Comment: @rudi_visser ah yes the old IE .ico problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Accessibility